# Primefaces excel export is not working - no open/save dialog is shown

Tags: jsf, export, primefaces, xls, mojarra

I am trying to export collection of dtos to excel with primefaces like this (the same as primefaces showcase demo, which is working).

```
<p:commandButton value="Export">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="results" fileName="game_statistics" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I observed with firebug and it makes request, also the response looks like file content, but no file save/open dialog is popping.
I am using mojarra 2.1.1 and tomcat 6 for app server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>` sends by default an ajax request. You can't download files with ajax. Ajax is executed by Javascript, but Javascript has due to security restrictions no way to force a *Save As* dialogue and pass the ajax response to it.

You need to add `ajax="false"` to the component:

```
<p:commandButton value="Export" ajax="false">
```

Or just use a regular `<h:commandButton>`:

```
<h:commandButton value="Export">
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose it into `<h:form>...</h:form>` and it will work
For example:

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton value="Export">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="results" fileName="game_statistics" />
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces doesn't support dynamic columns if you're using ones (by dynamic column I mean dynamic column attributes values). You can use POI for a workaround, but I don't know what exactly are you trying to do. 
Show us some code.
What version of Primefaces are you using?

Comment: I use poi-3.2-FINAL, poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL,primefaces-2.2.1, jsf-api-2.1.1-b01, isf-impl-2.1.1-b01.
.....
`code`
<p:commandButton value="Export">
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="results" fileName="game_statistics" />
</p:commandButton>
.....
<p:dataTable id="results" var="gameTotalReport" value="#{gamesTotalReportBean.gameTotalReports}" rendered="#{gamesTotalReportBean.gameTotalReports != null}" 
        paginator="true" rows="7"  
                  paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
`code`

Comment: Please edit/update your question by adding the full code there with `code formatting`

Answer (score -2):

I have a form page and I want to use filters from it and apply some validations before extracting data from the managed bean (jpa repository) when I click the `commandButton`, but the behavior of `dataExporter` it's to export the file right away, and then if I click again I get the right results, since the bean already worked on it at the first action...

Using the `preProcessor` option of dataExporter as a first step does the job, but I know it's not the right way to do this (should use for doc formatting etc), but I didn't find any other way to solve this (p.s. my case is for Export Page Data Only, not rendering the dataTable), does anyone have an alternative/solution for that?

Comment: Preprocessor is in no way (100% sure) a solution for opening (or not) of a dialog

Comment: _"does anyone have an alternative/solution for that?"_ sounds like a question... Belongs in a new question...

Comment: it's the same situation as the question, except for the bean part not working properly... as I said, it works but it's not right to do, so I'm asking for an alternative... I don't get the downvotes anyway

Comment: Downvotes because of several reasons: 1: No code for a solution 2: No code related to **your** original problem that did not work, 3: No code related to the original question 4: cannot imagine (partly due to the missing code) that this is a solution for the problem, 5: so it is a hard to use solution to implement for others 6: I would not want others to try to implement this since it feels very hacky and might have just solved another invisible problem by e.g. getting a new fresh deploy..

Comment: as mentioned, it's the same situation, except for the bean part, so I have something like this:
`<h:form prependId="false"> <p:commandButton update=":content:tableResult" ajax="false" action="#{bean.validateSearch()}" > <p:dataExporter target=":content:tableResult" pageOnly="true"/> </p:commandButton> </h:form> <h:form prependId="false"> <p:dataTable id="tableResult" value="#{bean.data}" rendered="false"> </h:form>` this doesn't work, unless if I use the `commandButton` action as a `preProcessor` in the `dataExporter`, it's not the right way but is the behavior I expected for the code above.

Comment: any suggestions would be appreciated.